# Animate TabBar color change

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I have an `UITabBar` that each tab changes its color on tap.

I want it to be animated (0.5 seconds between notSelectedColor to SelectedColor), how can I do that?

I'm re-drawing the image with the color like that:

```
func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, size.height)
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0)
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, CGBlendMode.Normal)

    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size)
    CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, CGImage)
    color.setFill()
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    return newImage
}
```

thank you!

Comment: @ChiragPatel I just wanna animate the color, isn't there any quicker way?

Answer (score 3):

You can animate the tab color by following code:

```
let tabBar: UITabBar? = self.tabBarController?.tabBar
        UIView.transitionWithView(tabBar!, duration: 1.0, options: [.BeginFromCurrentState, .TransitionCrossDissolve], animations: {
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
            }, completion: nil)
```

I have also made a sample project for you. Download the [sample project here](http://www.dropbox.com/s/16d55nnlstm9k0n/TestTabs%202.zip?dl=0).

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But I want it to fade between `TabBar.image` and `TabBar.selectedImage` when it tapped. Can you please help me with this? Thanks!